# Hadoop BigTop on centOS. Not able to run MapReduce Application - FlightsByCarrier

Tags: mapreduce

I am learning Hadoop using the Hadoop for Dummies. I have successfully run thr first steps like installation, creating HDFS and storing Data, running Pig scripts etc.
I have created the FlightsByCarries.jar File.

When I run the code as given in the book, I am getting an error:

```
[root@localhost totalmiles]# hadoop jar /home/tom/Desktop/totalmiles/FlightsByCarrier.jar FlightsByCarrier /user/root/airline-data/2008.csv /user/root/output/flightsCount
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FlightsByCarrier
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

Could someone please help me correct this?

Answer (score 0):

it is because your compiler is not getting your main method in the jar FlightsByCarrier. may be you haven't copy the file to hdfs or your file path is not appropriate...check once..and then try

Answer (score 0):

You JAR file is unable to locate the main class name, if you are using any package name in your main class then specify complete name along with package while running the program.

Ex:
 ***hadoop jar FlightsByCarrier.jar com.dev.FlightsByCarrier /input /output***

You can also include main class while creating JAR file.

While creating a JAR file after selecting the path then click next --> asks for selecting main class --> browse the name and select --> click OK

Run the command without class name in this case.

***hadoop jar FlightsByCarrier.jar /input /output***

Hope this solves your problem.